# How to get the five least repeating elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays, search, output

If I have the following array of strings.

```
String inStrings[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B"};
```

And this array is later passed to a method, that I am not sure how to proceed with.

```
    static void getColdSearch(String[] inArray){



}
```

What this method is supposed to do is to take the array, get the strings that repeat the least and then print out the five least repeating strings in the output. The repeating strings would not have to be next to one-another and if there are fewer then five Strings then all should be part of the output. E.g. if the arraylist looks like the example above the output should look something like this.

```
F //(Occurs once)
G //(Occurs once)
H //(Occurs once)
E //(Occurs twice)
D //(if two different elements repeat the same number of times a random one of them should be printed)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a `Map`, with the letter in the array as a key, and the value be a counter. Then find the 5 with the lowest values, and you're set. Get to it.

Comment: step 1.  count each element.  step 2 court the counts from least to most frequent.  step 3 return the first file elements of the sorted list built in step 2.

Comment: You should try _something_ first. If it doesn't work, then ask for help. Don't ask us to solve something for you.

Comment: this sounds like a homework assignment - what have you tried so far and where exactly lies your problem?

Comment: It is an assignment and I had no idea where to start, so thank's to this, I'll try with a HashMap, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try java 8 features

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GroupingDemo {

    public static void getColdSearch(String[] inArray) {
        Map<String, Long> groupingByLetter = Arrays.stream(inArray)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

        List<String> result = groupingByLetter.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .limit(5)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inStrings[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B"};
        getColdSearch(inStrings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Max Heap(Priority Queue) and  Hash Map .

Create a Class

```
         Class WordCount
          {
             String word;
             int count;
           }  
           PriorityQueue<WordCount>queue // queue to save minimum repeated words
           HashMap<String,Integer>map // save data for each word
```

Loop through the array

For the first 5 unique words save in queue

check the data in map . If word exists update the count

check the top element in queue . if the count of the word is higher than the current index word , then remove the word from queue and add this word . 
Repeat the process till end of the loop .

At last poll all the elements from the queue

Answer (score 1):

You could use Java 8 as outlined above. Here is a solution that perhaps assists in understanding how one can perform the same in Java 7 or earlier. Plus, I think it is helpful to understand what really is happening under the hood.

```
static void getColdSearch(String[] inArray) {
    Map<String, Integer> counterMap = new HashMap<>();


    // load the array in a Map instance
    for (String in : inArray) {
        if (null != counterMap.putIfAbsent(in, 1) ) {
        counterMap.put(in, counterMap.get(in) + 1);
        }
    }

    // Question: why do we need a priority queue?
    // We could also use sort based on the values. Search 
    // stackoverflow.com for "sorting on map value"
    PriorityQueue<String> heap = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // sort based on the count.
        return counterMap.get(o1).compareTo(counterMap.get(o2));
        }

    });


    heap.addAll(counterMap.keySet());

    int size = heap.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // you could end it a "5" but I leave that as an exercise.
        String s = heap.poll();
        System.out.println( s + " count: " + counterMap.get(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you immensely! This really helped!